# How to get an attached file from document context (handle request for uploaded file) domino

Tags: java, file-upload, document, lotus-domino

I am new to domino.

I trying to handle a file upload request in Java agent of domino. 
I assumed that it should be an embedded object in document context, but it is NOT there. 
I don't know any other way, Is there a way to get the file which is sent as a post request? How does the domino handles it.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution to uploading files is just to create a Form containing a FileUpload field and then move or process the file in the QuerySave agent. Don't think you can upload files to and web agent.

Good links:

[How To: Upload Files To Domino From Flex](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20090819)

[Adding Your Own File Uploads to Forms](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20051125?OpenDocument)

/Not soo much newb anymore

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the attachment is embedded into a RichText element in the document. To access it, iterate through the document.items and find an item of type RICHTEXT. Then you can check it for embedded objects.

There is a useful domino object map located [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_Domino_Object_map_8.5.1)

/Newbs